# Using tsconfig-paths with a project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tsconfig-paths

I'd like to setup [tsconfig-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths) for [this project](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fireflysemantics/validator).

I'm not sure what I need to do after installing `tsconfig-paths` as a dev dependency.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin has to be registered dynamically via the command line for each script that is run.  For example I have a data generate script in `test/data/generate/index.ts`.  In order to run this script, which imports from `@fs/utilities` I need to do:

```
npx ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register test/data/generate/index.ts
```

For my use cases this is enough as I have few scripts that need to be run dynamically inside the typescript project.  For example for [@fireflysemantics/validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fireflysemantics/validator) everything exported is intended to be used by external dependencies, thus there are no cases where I need to run data generation scripts.